# why apt-get installing both openjdk-7 and openjdk-8

Tags: apt, java, openjdk

So initially when I tried `$ls /usr/lib/jvm`

`no such directory`

Then I tried `$sudo apt-get install openjdk-8*`

Now for `$ls /usr/lib/jvm` gives

```
java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64  java-7-openjdk-amd64  openjdk-7
java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64  java-8-openjdk-amd64  openjdk-8
```

Then for `java -version`

```
java version "1.7.0_111"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.7) (7u111-2.6.7-2~deb8u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.111-b01, mixed mode)
```

i.e by default it sets to java version `7`.

And my problem is

1. why this is installing both `java` versions
2. And why it's `openjdk-7` by default.

I want `openjdk-8` by default. Any help on this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use update-alternatives to set the default java installation for your system. This program will manage which program installation will fulfill generic programs for which there are many versions and/or alternatives.

sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/ jdk1.8.0/bin/java"

Comment: Thank you for you answer. But i want to know why It's installing both `openjdk`s?

Comment: I wasn't sure about that one. Possibly some misconfigured dependency problem?